# Plotting data from different columns on same ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show data that essentially uses "open" shapes when a value in a certain column is greater than 0.05, and uses "closed" shapes when a value in a certain column is less than 0.05.

My intuition was to have the same set of values in two columns, but to make certain values in each copy of the two variables missing, such that when I could use `geom_point()` for each column but with different shapes (open and closed), all the data would appear but according to the rule I specified above. I also do other things in the `ggplot2`, such as implementing a group-by-outcome structure, that I would like to carry through for both columns.

That is probably a way to melt the figures, but if that is the case then I do not know how to implement the (likely) required conditional.

Please see my example below for what I am attempting to do.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
    outcome = c("Outcome 1","Outcome 2", "Outcome 3", "Outcome 1","Outcome 2", "Outcome 3", "Outcome 1","Outcome 2", "Outcome 3"),
    sample = c("Indiana", "Indiana", "Indiana", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia"),
    pvals_open = c(0.095, 0.120, 0.420, NA, 0.192, 0.121, NA, 0.22, 0.30),
    pvals_closed = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.029, NA, NA, 0.043, NA, NA)
)

pd <- position_dodge(0.8)

picture <- ggplot(df, aes(x = outcome, y = pvals_open, group = sample, colour = sample)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = sample), size = 2, alpha = 1, position = pd) +
    # Use geom_point to make points look open
    geom_point(aes(shape = sample), size = 1, alpha = 1, position = pd, color = "white") +
    # Would like to incorporate points from pvals_closed
    geom_point(data = df, aes(x = outcome, y = pvals_closed, group = sample, colour = sample)) +
    # Doesn't quite work. For Outcome 1, black circle should be a black square that is slightly above 
    # orange triangle (but not directly so), and green cicle should be below (but not directly so)
    # Three colors for Indiana, Colorado, and Virginia. Would like this to hold for both sets of pval
    scale_colour_manual(values = c('#91D699', '#F95A36', '#000000')) +  
    # Other features I'd like to include
    coord_flip(ylim = c(0,1)) + 
    theme(
    legend.justification=c(0, 1),
    legend.position = "none",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    text = element_text(size=11),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = 'grey75'),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(size=14),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

Here is the picture I've made:

[image: Here is the picture I've made.]

If anyone has any solutions/guidance, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something here, but it seems like you are representing the sample by both color and shape and not adding anything extra by having both. Maybe this could be simplified by using just color to denote the sample and then use shape to represent whether a point is over/under 0.05. Even easier you could just add a line at the 0.05 position and it'll be easy to tell which ones are over/under.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data_frame(
  outcome = c("Outcome 1","Outcome 2", "Outcome 3", "Outcome 1","Outcome 2", "Outcome 3", "Outcome 1","Outcome 2", "Outcome 3"),
  sample = c("Indiana", "Indiana", "Indiana", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia"),
  pvals_open = c(0.095, 0.120, 0.420, NA, 0.192, 0.121, NA, 0.22, 0.30),
  pvals_closed = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.029, NA, NA, 0.043, NA, NA)
)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    val = coalesce(pvals_open, pvals_closed),
    sig = if_else(val > 0.05, "> 0.05", "<= 0.05")
  ) %>% 
  select(outcome, sample, val, sig)

ggplot(df2) +
  aes(x = outcome, y = val, group = sample, colour = sample, shape = sig) +
  geom_point(size = 2, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.05, linetype = "dotted") +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(0,1)) +
  theme(
    # legend.justification=c(0, 1),
    # legend.position = "none",
    # legend.title = element_blank(),
    # legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    text = element_text(size=11),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = 'grey75'),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(size=14),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Created on 2018-10-14 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you - I think your argument about simplification makes sense. I'll give this the check.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(
  outcome = c("Outcome 1","Outcome 2", "Outcome 3", "Outcome 1","Outcome 2", "Outcome 3", "Outcome 1","Outcome 2", "Outcome 3"),
  sample = c("Indiana", "Indiana", "Indiana", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia"),
  pvals = c(0.095, 0.120, 0.420, 0.029, 0.192, 0.121, 0.043, 0.22, 0.30),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> xdf

# use this for the shape factor control

xdf$shape <- ifelse(xdf$pvals >= 0.05, "open", "closed")
xdf$shape <- sprintf("%s-%s", xdf$sample, xdf$shape)

# we'll use position_nudge() but we need to specify the values manually
# since position can't be mapped to an aesthetic. You could (fairly easily)
# use some logic to programmatically set the values here vs the hard
# coding that I did (have to leave some work for the OP ;-)

ggplot(xdf) +
  geom_point(
    aes(pvals, outcome, group = sample, colour = sample, shape = shape),
    position = position_nudge(y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, -0.1, -0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)),
    size = 3, stroke=1
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = NULL,
    values = c(
      "Indiana" = "#F95A36",
      "Colorado" = "#91D699",
      "Virginia" = "#000000"
    )
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual( # here's how we get shape aeshetic mapping
    name = NULL,
    values = c(
      "Indiana-open" = 24, 
      "Indiana-closed" = 17, 
      "Colorado-open" = 1,
      "Colorado-closed" = 19, 
      "Virginia-open" = 0, 
      "Virginia-closed" = 15
    ),
    labels = c( # you have no legend for what the points actually mean but just in case you decide to do that, here are better labels for ^^
      "Colorado (p>=0.5)",
      "Colorado (p<0.5)",
      "Indiana (p>=0.5)",
      "Indiana (p<0.5)",
      "Virginia (p>=0.5)", 
      "Virginia (p<0.5)"
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 11),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = 'grey75'),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    legend.justification = c(0, 1),
    legend.position = "none",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA)
  )
```

[image]